# Append text to a text file from a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have two files in one directory, `Test.bat` and `Test.txt`.

`Test.txt` content before:

> ```
> I am a simple text.
> ```

`Test.bat` content, *(executed with admin rights)*:

```
echo First (1st) line >> Test.txt
echo Second (2nd) line >> Test.txt
```

But nothing happens. `Test.txt` file remains unchanged. Why?

`Test.txt` expected content after:

> ```
> I am a simple text.First (1st) line
> Second (2nd) line
> ```

I don't want to give the full path because it varies. However, both files are in the same folder. That has to work!

Comment: Based on your provided information I have no problems at all running your code and getting the expected output.

Comment: Are you chosing the Run As Administrator from the Explorer Context Menu when you run this batch file.  If so, that is the problem because the working directory defaults to SYSTEM32 when you do that.

Comment: Yes Im running with windows explorer context menu "Run As Administrator". 
So if I run with an installer the .bat File it should work?

Comment: Don't know the answer to that question because I know nothing about the installer or how it runs.

Comment: Yes but it should be able to run the bat with windows explorer? Or can't I do this with batch?

Comment: Unless you aleady know for sure beforehand that your text file is not terminated by an appropriate Windows carriage return and line feed combination, your expected result wouldn't reflect mine. Please clarify whether the last line of `Test.txt` is terminated, and if so does it use LF, _(Unix)_, CR, _(Mac)_, or CRLF, _(Windows)_, line terminators. Please also note that we can only test the code you've provided, so if you have not provided all the important code and/or information then your actual task must reflect ours.

Comment: The installer might be executing your elevated cmd.exe within a temporary folder that it creates when it unpacks the package contents.  It's also possible you are trying to modify immutable files.  Running elevated does not always provide sufficient privileges to modify some protected files on the system.  What your process sees is a shadow copy of the file, then when some other process comes along that has not modified that file, it sees the officially sanction file.   Perhaps you are attempting to hack the system in ways that are not supported by Microsoft?

Comment: Because this a debugging problem that cannot be reproduced without additional and more accurate context, I vote to close.